# Is the value of Content-Length actually of any significance?

Tags: http, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse, httpserver

I use the following command to start a webserver. However, when I use a brower to access the server, I can see the whole string of `Hello World!` despite that Content-Length is only 1.

```
sed 's/$/\r/g' <<EOF | netcat -l -p 8080
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 1

Hello World!
EOF
```

This suggest that the actual value of Content-Length is insignficant although `Content-Length` has to be specified in the response. Is it so?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. See https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#header.content-length for HTTP/1.1. In general, for HTTP/1.1, it is of big significance. For HTTP/1.o it is not unless you use persistent connections. For HTTP/2 it's not needed anymore except as hint.